# Thymeleaf form for each object in list results in "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object"

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have multiple objects inside a list and wanted to create a form for every object in that List (the user can only submit one object at once). But as soon as I use th:field instead of name and value I get an exception. Maybe someone can help me. It only happens when using the th:each; if I pass in a single object to the form it works... I reduced the problem to the minimum so its more readable :)

Exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'o' available as request attribute

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/objectlisttest")
    public ModelAndView getObjectListTest() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("objectlisttest");
        List<DataObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            DataObject o = new DataObject();
            o.setText("Dataobject");
            objects.add(o);
        }
        mv.addObject("objects", objects);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping("/objectlisttest")
    public ModelAndView editObjectListTest(DataObject o, BindingResult br) {
        System.out.println(o);
        return getObjectListTest();
    }

    public static class DataObject {
        private String text;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

}
```

View:

```
<div th:each="o : ${objects}">
    <form th:object="${o}" th:action="@{/objectlisttest}" method="POST">
        <label>Text<input type="text" th:field="*{text}"></label>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Changing the View to

```
<div th:each="o : ${objects}">
    <form th:object="${o}" th:action="@{/objectlisttest}" method="POST">
        <label>Text<input type="text" th:value="*{text}" th:name="text"></label> 
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

works. But th:field would be much nicer...

Comment: hey, I am facing similar problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: The truth is, that i switched to using angular in the frontend. I think that it allowes better user experience than any kind of server side rendering. It takes a bit more time in the beginning but pays off later.

Answer (score 0):

It expects to have "o" object in model. If you call

```
mv.addObject("o", someObject);
```

The error disappear I think but there would be a conflict between "o" in model and "o" as a loop variable.

I would say it's not good idea to add multiple forms with the same reference to model (all the forms has `th:object="${o}"`).

You should redesign the logic. Either place each object separately in the model or create just one form to keep list.

Comment: I could pass a seperate object to the th:object, but then I cant use th:field. I have to use th:value and th:name but this could work. I was searching for a way to tell thymeleaf the name of the "target object" of a form